# AngularJS URL's with HTML5 mode doesn't work

Tags: html, angularjs

Using the AngularJS SPA template for visual studio.  Inside my app.js I have:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('touranalysis', {
        url: '/touranalysis',
        templateUrl: '/views/touranalysis/index',
        controller: 'tourAnalysisCtrl'
    })
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

If I'm running locally and click on my link for touranalysis it works fine.  Here's the link in my nav bar.

```
<a href="~/touranalysis">Tour Analysis</a>
```

But if I'm on that page, which is

```
http://localhost:8080/touranalysis
```

and I click F5, I get a page not found error.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't have touranalysis page in your server. You are getting page not found error because the browser requests touranalysis page when you click F5. Angular routing will work after you have your page loaded. If I am correct, your template is using ASP.NET MVC. So you can add a custom route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
       name: "touranalysis",
       url: "touranalysis",
       defaults: new { controller = "touranalysisController", action = "Index" });
```

This way ASP.NET MVC will load Index view of touranalysisController which should contain ng-view. After that Angularjs will load /views/touranalysis/index

I hope this helps. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I'm confused about the mixing of MVC and angularjs routing.  I actually have no MVC controllers, just api controllers I'm using for all server side processing (CRUD).  Why should I need to add a route in 2 places, and create MVC controllers when they aren't doing anything?

Comment: I just looked at the angularJS SPA template and it doesn't use MVC routing

Comment: OK, I thought you were using [this Angular SPA template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cc6c9c5f-2846-4822-899f-a6c295cd4f2b) Anyway, The point is that your browser is looking for touranalysis page which doesn't exist. ASP.NET WEB API template has a Views folder where are .schtml files and App_Start folder which contains RouteConfig.cs. Do you have that files in your template? Where did you add ng-view?